# How to convert an array of object to a Table?

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I have an array of objects like this:

```
[{"product_id":10006683,"detail_id":72,"serial":125655},{"product_id":10006683,"detail_id":72,"serial":125655}]
```

Now I want to convert it to a temporary table. How can I do?

Comment: Which version of MySQL you are using?

Comment: mysqld  Ver 10.3.20-MariaDB for Linux on x86_64 (MariaDB Server)

Comment: Then use the function called [json_table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-table-functions.html)

Comment: your question is not clear you are telling that you want to create a temporary table from an array of objects. you mean your column will be product_id,details_id,seiral_id in that temporary table or you just you want to save that array into a column?? which one do you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MariaDb doesn't have a JSON_TABLE function like MySql 8.0

But you can use a recursive CTE to unfold the json array.

Then use those results for the temporary table.

**For example:**

> ```
> DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS tmp_table;
> CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_table
> (
>   id integer primary key auto_increment,
>   product_id integer,
>   detail_id integer, 
>   serial integer
> );
> ```

> ```
> set @json = '[{"product_id":10006683,"detail_id":72,"serial":125655},{"product_id":10006684,"detail_id":73,"serial":129655}]';
>
> insert into tmp_table (product_id, detail_id, serial)
> with recursive rcte_json as
> (
>   select 1 n
>   , JSON_EXTRACT(@json, '$[0].product_id') as product_id
>   , JSON_EXTRACT(@json, '$[0].detail_id') as detail_id
>   , JSON_EXTRACT(@json, '$[0].serial') as serial
>
>   union all
>
>   select n+1
>   , JSON_EXTRACT(@json, concat('$[',n,'].product_id')) as product_id
>   , JSON_EXTRACT(@json, concat('$[',n,'].detail_id')) as detail_id
>   , JSON_EXTRACT(@json, concat('$[',n,'].serial')) as serial
>   from rcte_json
>   where n < JSON_LENGTH(@json)
> )
> select product_id, detail_id, serial
> from rcte_json
> order by n;
> ```

> ```
> select * from tmp_table
> ```
>
> ```
> id | product_id | detail_id | serial
> -: | ---------: | --------: | -----:
>  1 |   10006683 |        72 | 125655
>  2 |   10006684 |        73 | 129655
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=b46dd6cce9cfa235f81f9179362738b2)*

Comment: It depends.  If you can reach the element with a certain JSONPath (google it, it's a standard like XPath for xml) then you can use that for more JSON_EXTRACT.  But something like unfolding  nested arrays would be rather tricky.

Answer (score 0):

MariaDB currently has no function to convert a JSON object into a table. The `JSON_TABLE()` function is currently under development and planned for MariaDB 10.5 (see [MDEV-17399](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-17399)).

An alternative would be to create the tables via a script, e.g. with [json-to-mysql](https://github.com/adamwulf/json-to-mysql) or if it's a one time job using an online converter like [SQLizer](https://sqlizer.io)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the sequence engine instead of a recursive CTE:

```
set @json = '[{"product_id":10006683,"detail_id":72,"serial":125655},{"product_id":10006684,"detail_id":73,"serial":129655}]';

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_table AS
  select seq + 1 AS id,
   JSON_EXTRACT(@json, concat('$[',seq,'].product_id')) as product_id
  , JSON_EXTRACT(@json, concat('$[',seq,'].detail_id')) as detail_id
  , JSON_EXTRACT(@json, concat('$[',seq,'].serial')) as serial
  from seq_0_to_1000 WHERE seq < JSON_LENGTH(@json);
```

with deeply nested documents, you can use this and/or recursive CTEs in combination to extract the full structure. Think

```
FROM seq_0_to_1000 AS top 
LEFT JOIN seq_0_to_1000 AS l1 ON l1.seq < JSON_LENGTH(JSON_EXTRACT(@json, concat('$[',top.seq,'].children')))
WHERE top.seq < JSON_LENGTH(@json);
```

EDIT: I ended up needing a general parser, so the below will extract all the leaf nodes (well, any sub-node, but I filtered out everything but the leaves). Further, it includes the JPATH to each leaf, so you can find specific subsets of values.

```
WITH RECURSIVE r AS (SELECT 
    t.id, # TODO: 2) add any passthrough values here and in the next UNION. Both must have the same number. 
    t.j AS full,
    1 AS depth,
    CONCAT('$', CASE JSON_TYPE(t.j) WHEN 'OBJECT' THEN CONCAT('.', JSON_VALUE(JSON_KEYS(t.j), CONCAT('$[', s.seq, ']'))) WHEN 'ARRAY' THEN CONCAT('[', s.seq, ']') ELSE '' END) AS full_key,
    JSON_VALUE(JSON_KEYS(t.j), CONCAT('$[', s.seq, ']')) AS the_key,
    JSON_UNQUOTE(CASE JSON_TYPE(t.j)
      WHEN 'ARRAY' THEN JSON_EXTRACT(t.j, CONCAT('$[', s.seq, ']'))
      WHEN 'OBJECT' THEN JSON_EXTRACT(t.j, CONCAT('$.', JSON_QUOTE(JSON_VALUE(JSON_KEYS(t.j), CONCAT('$[', s.seq, ']')))))
      ELSE JSON_UNQUOTE(t.j)
    END) AS the_value, 
    JSON_LENGTH(t.j) > 1000 AS is_too_many_keys_or_items
# TODO: 1) Add data below, json field needs to be aliased to `j`.
  FROM (SELECT 1 AS id, '{"a": "a", "b":3, "cd":["c","d"]}' AS j UNION SELECT 2, '["e", "f"]' UNION SELECT 3, '"g"' UNION SELECT 4, '1' UNION SELECT 5, 2 UNION SELECT 6, 'h' UNION SELECT 7, '{"a": "a", "b":"b", "cd":["c","d"], "asdf": {"asd": 3, "ff": [3,4,5,{"ad": 35}]}}') AS t 
  LEFT JOIN seq_0_to_1000 AS s ON s.seq < JSON_LENGTH(t.j)
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT 
    r.id, # TODO: 2) add any passthrough values here as you did in the previous UNION. Both must have the same number. 
    r.full, 
    r.depth + 1 AS depth,
    CONCAT(r.full_key, IFNULL(CONCAT('.', JSON_VALUE(JSON_KEYS(r.the_value), CONCAT('$[', s.seq, ']'))), CONCAT('[', s.seq, ']'))) AS full_key,
    JSON_VALUE(JSON_KEYS(r.the_value), CONCAT('$[', s.seq, ']')) AS the_key,
    JSON_UNQUOTE(CASE JSON_TYPE(r.the_value)
      WHEN 'ARRAY' THEN JSON_EXTRACT(r.the_value, CONCAT('$[', s.seq, ']'))
      WHEN 'OBJECT' THEN JSON_EXTRACT(r.the_value, CONCAT('$.', JSON_QUOTE(JSON_VALUE(JSON_KEYS(r.the_value), CONCAT('$[', s.seq, ']')))))
    END) AS the_value, 
    r.is_too_many_keys_or_items + JSON_LENGTH(r.the_value) > 1000 AS is_too_many_keys_or_items
  FROM r
  JOIN seq_0_to_1000 AS s ON s.seq < JSON_LENGTH(r.the_value) AND JSON_TYPE(r.the_value) IN ('ARRAY', 'OBJECT'))
SELECT * /* TODO: 3) reformate as needed */ FROM r WHERE IFNULL(JSON_TYPE(r.the_value), '') NOT IN ('ARRAY', 'OBJECT') ORDER BY 1,3,4;
```

EDIT: added JSON_QUOTE to defend against JPath injections.

Answer (score -2):

```
/*Try This*/

<?php 
$dbhost = 'localhost'; /* Hostname */
$dbuser = 'dbusername'; /* Database Username*/ 
$dbpass = 'dbpassword'; /* Database Password*/
$database = 'dbname'; /* Database Name*/ 

$conn = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $database); /*database connection here*/

$json = '[{"product_id":10006683,"detail_id":72,"serial":125655},{"product_id":10006683,"detail_id":72,"serial":125655}]'; /*Array of object*/

$jsonData = json_decode($json);/*decode json data */

/* print_r($jsonData); */

foreach($jsonData as $json){
$product_id = $json->product_id; /* product_id */
$detail_id = $json->detail_id; /*detail_id*/
$serial = $json->serial; /*serial*/
$sql = "INSERT INTO TableName "."(product_id,detail_id, serial) "."VALUES "."('$product_id','$detail_id','$serial')";

}
$retval = mysqli_query( $sql, $conn );
if(! $retval ) {
     die('Could not enter data: ' . mysqli_error());
}
echo "Entered data successfully\n";
mysqli_close($conn);


?>
```